# Connecting flight from Tel-Aviv to Venice

Tags: short-connections, fco

I fly from Tel Aviv to Venice via Rome (Fiumicino). Between flights I have only one hour. The same airline (Alitalia). Is it really hard to catch the second flight? How should I act?

Comment: If the airline is willing to sell you the flights on a single ticket, they belive you can make it (and are ready to shoulder the cost of rebooking you if you don't). If not, don't risk it. Are you asking specifically for instructions on how to transfer between terminals as Fiumincino?

Answer (score 1):

Every airline has a Minimum Connection Time set and below that the system won't issue a ticket for you. But that is a thing set in computers, not always the reality. Like, the relevant MCT for this connection is 45 minutes but for about an hour in the morning and in the evening (which is alas when the flight from TLV lands) the transit area becomes a spectacular chaos. If you want to make this connection, make sure you are as close to the front as possible, deplane and move quick.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you :

1. Check your Fare rule about change
2. Call Alitalia and ask to change te reservation with the requested flight .

If you would you like to change your flight ticket that you already purchased ,even if is just the next flight ,it is follow the same rule of a any change on your flight ticket .

Anyway a free change request could be authorized from the airline , since it's just for short connection time